# Should I use weight or volume when measuring doses?

Tags: drip-brew, pour-over

My pour over/drip coffee pot recommends that I measure 10-12g of coffee per person whilst my grinder has markings to indicate whether the ground amount is for 1 or 2 cups. I notice that darker roasts being slightly more oily seem to weigh more and therefore the volume is less compared to a lighter roast so the question is which method of measuring is correct?

I understand that taste is subjective and I have been using 11g so far but given the variability in weight and volume is there a correct method which perhaps can be adjusted for different roast types?

Comment: Actually, a darker roast will weigh less, because it will have lost mass. The oil you see on the surface is also present in a light roast as well, but it is still captured in the cells of the bean, so it's not readily visible.

Comment: @keithjgrant yes I think you're right as I just switched to a dark roast this morning and noticed the volume was higher, also that it's far easier to grind using a hand grinder compared to a lighter roast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cooking in general weighting dry ingredients would be much more precise and give you greater control over your variables.